# JSON.parse() silently fails

Tags: json, parsing, jqplot

I'm working on a Windows desktop application, which contains an object of type System::Windows::Forms::WebBrowser.  The application processes some performance data and displays an HTML page with various graphs (histograms, pie charts etc).

It works as follows:

- The application generates an HTML file on a local temp path (e.g., .../local/path/myfile.html)
- The application's WebBrowser object navigates to the file generated:

  webBrowser1->Navigate(".../local/path/myfile.html")
- jQuery and some other plugins (e.g., jqPlot) are used to create various graphs and myfile.html is rendered within the applicaion

**myfile.html contains a section of code:**

```
<div id="frame-time-histograms">
    <div id="frame-time-histogram-1">
        <div id="frame-time-histogram-1-target-plot" class="histogram-target" style="height:250px; width:900px;"></div>
        <div id="frame-time-histogram-1-controller-plot" class="histogram-controller" style="height:100px; width:900px;"></div>
        <script id="frame-time-histogram-1-data" class="histogram-data" type="text/plain">
            [{"type" : "Type 1", "shortest" : 12, "longest" : 74}, [[0, 0], [1, 12.632], [2, 16.619], [3, 16.592], [4, 16.664], [5, 16.586]]]
        </script>
    </div>
    <div id="frame-time-histogram-2">
        <div id="frame-time-histogram-2-target-plot" class="histogram-target" style="height:250px; width:900px;"></div>
        <div id="frame-time-histogram-2-controller-plot" class="histogram-controller" style="height:100px; width:900px;"></div>
        <script id="frame-time-histogram-2-data" class="histogram-data" type="text/plain">
            [{"type" : "Type 2", "shortest" : 24, "longest" : 19}, [[0, 0], [1, 20.145], [2, 20.091], [3, 20.301], [4, 20.109], [5, 20.087]]]
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: Here I'm using script tags as data containers for my histograms.

**My JavaScript file contains a section of code:**

```
var histograms = $('div#frame-time-histograms');
histograms.children().each(function(index) {
    var histogramTargetId = $(this).find('div.histogram-target').attr('id');
    var histogramControllerId = $(this).find('div.histogram-controller').attr('id');

    var histogramData = JSON.parse($(this).find('script.histogram-data').html());
```

However JSON.parse() doesn't seem to do anything.  I've added alert("hello") to before and after this line but only the first one is executed.

If I go to the temp path and double click on myfile.html, JSON.parse() works fine.  I can see all the graphs in my web browser (Chrome, FF and IE).

Would anybody be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If only the first `alert` is called then the problem is that JSON is failing. Is there some sort of a JSON lib available and working?

Comment: @Kirstein - Thanks for your response.  It's turned out that the WebBrowser I'm using within the application is < IE8 and it doesn't have native JSON support.  If I include the Crockford's JSON2 parser, the histograms are displayed correctly.

i.e.,

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that jqPlot provides its version of json2.js file:

```
...\plugins\jqplot.json2.js
```

To work around the problem I was having, I have included this js file in myfile.html and changed

```
JSON.parse($(this).find('script.histogram-data').html());
```

to

```
$.jqplot.JSON.parse($(this).find('script.histogram-data').html());
```

Comment: +1 getting a solution. If this solved your problem go ahead accept your answer. So all know this question is answered.